# Including AndroidX libraries into Unity project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, aar, androidx

I'm getting missing class errors when I run my Unity app. I have a native code library I wrote compiled as an aar. I've just updated some code to support local notifications on Android 8 and I've used the Android X "Worker" class. My aar compiles fine but I guess I'm missing a library to include in the Unity project. Which library should I be adding?

The error is

```
06-05 10:57:52.970: E/AndroidRuntime(21759): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[com.help.stressfree.localnotifications.NotificationService]
06-05 10:57:52.970: E/AndroidRuntime(21759): Process: com.help.stressfree, PID: 21759
06-05 10:57:52.970: E/AndroidRuntime(21759): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/work/Data$Builder;
06-05 10:57:52.970: E/AndroidRuntime(21759):    at com.help.stressfree.localnotifications.NotificationService.ScheduleNotification(NotificationService.java:99)
06-05 10:57:52.970: E/AndroidRuntime(21759):    at com.help.stressfree.localnotifications.NotificationService.onHandleIntent(NotificationService.java:82)
06-05 10:57:52.970: E/AndroidRuntime(21759):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:68)
06-05 10:57:52.970: E/AndroidRuntime(21759):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
06-05 10:57:52.970: E/AndroidRuntime(21759):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
06-05 10:57:52.970: E/AndroidRuntime(21759):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
06-05 10:57:52.970: E/AndroidRuntime(21759): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.work.Data$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.help.stressfree-FN_ED1fyI9LY4tcsB1RWqQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.help.stressfree-FN_ED1fyI9LY4tcsB1RWqQ==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.help.stressfree-FN_ED1fyI9LY4tcsB1RWqQ==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
06-05 10:57:52.970: E/AndroidRuntime(21759):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
06-05 10:57:52.970: E/AndroidRuntime(21759):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
06-05 10:57:52.970: E/AndroidRuntime(21759):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

This is my gradle file for the aar library if it's relevant:

```
//indicates that this is a library
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            //Path to your source code
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java'
            }
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compileOnly files('libs/classes.jar', 'libs/libmessaging_unity_player_activity.jar')

    def work_version = "1.0.0-alpha02"

    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
}

//task to delete the old jar
task deleteOldJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'default/AndroidPlugin.jar'
}

//task to export contents as jar
task exportJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/default/')
    into('libs/jar')
    include('classes.jar')
    ///Rename the jar
    rename('classes.jar', 'AndroidPlugin.jar')

}

exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar, build)

//task to delete the old jar
task deleteOldAAR(type: Delete) {

}

//task to export contents as jar
task exportAAR(type: Copy) {
    from('build/outputs/aar/')
    into('libs/aars')
    include('app-debug.aar')
    ///Rename the jar
    rename('app-debug.aar', 'AndroidPlugin.aar')

}

exportAAR.dependsOn(deleteOldAAR, build)
```

Comment: I think you should post the actual error.

Comment: Updated the original post

Comment: In your project, where did you put the aar or jar plugin? Can we get also get a screenshot of the path? That would save some time

Comment: In the Unity project? The aar is in Assets\Plugins\Android

Comment: I think you should read [this](https://www.infoq.com/news/2018/05/androidx-library-alpha). It really matters. This AndroidX is still new I am wondering where the .jar lib that contains `Data$Builder` is located. It looks like everything changed. Wherever that jar is, you also have to put it at `Assets\Plugins\Android`.

Comment: That much I figured, my question is where is that jar/aar that I should be including

Comment: I don't know but I suspect [builder-3.1.2.jar](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.1.2/builder-3.1.2.jar). Give that a try and see of anything changes

Comment: Nope. I don't see any androidx classes in that jar

Comment: Did you try to use Google's Jar resolver plugin?

Comment: I just tried but run into this: https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/issues/145

Comment: The Jar resolver worked for me (eventually, once I figured out how it works) and my app works again!

Comment: @RealWorld How did you get the jar resolver working with androidx?

Comment: @TroyLamerton In <UnityProjectFolder>\Assets\PlayServicesResolver\Editor\AndroidDependencies.xml I added 
`<dependencies>
  <androidPackages>
    <androidPackage spec="com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"/>
 <androidPackage spec="com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"/>
  </androidPackages>
</dependencies>`
Which worked for me. Then just run the resolver from the Assets menu in Unity

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you have added your library as an `aar` file, which deos NOT include the library dependecies on it's own. If you are using Gradle, you should add the library dependencies as well, in this case `android-workmanager`.

So on these situations, do these solutions:

- On **Gradle** system, with an **aar** file.

  - Include library dependencies (on the library's `build.gradle` file on android studio) as well.
- On **Gradle** system, with library as a **maven** artifact:

  - Add the dependency and sync. Gradle will include the library dependencies itself.
- Using **Jar resolver**, with an **aar** file:

  - Same as Gradle, add the library dependecies to the xml file too.
- Using **Jar resolver**, with the **maven** artifact of the library

  - Add all dependencies to the editor xml.
- Using **internal** build system, with no dependency manager:

  - Get the aar or jar of all dependencies and add it beside the library.